# Gradle include jar during compile time but exclude runtime

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I'm using local jars and I need `javaee-api-6.0.jar` during compile time but I want to exclude it during runtime.

```
dependencies {
 
    // Add all the jar dependencies from the lib folder. 
    compile fileTree(dir: '../lib', include: ['/**/*.jar'])
    
   //testImplementation fileTree(dir: '../lib', excludes: ['/**/javaee-api-*.jar'])
}
```

I tried to exclude it during `testImplementation` but it doesn't help. runtime I got below error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'mycompany.persistence.HibernateBackwardsCompatibilifier#0' defined in class path resource 
[hibernateBeans.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate 
[mycompany.persistence.HibernateBackwardsCompatibilifier]: Constructor threw exception; nested 
exception is java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or
 abstract in class file javax/persistence/PersistenceException
```

How can I **include** jar during compile time but **exclude runtime**

Comment: What do you need a build tool for if you’re adding jars from a local directory? Last time that was done, the year was 1999.

Comment: Exactly... I've a Enterprise project older than 1999.. I'm on POC to move things from On-Prem to cloud... I need to prove the things for approvals.

Answer (score 1):

`compileOnly` — for dependencies that are necessary to compile your production code but shouldn’t be part of the runtime classpath

see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html#sec:java_dependency_management_overview

Answer (score 0):

I used below trick.

```
dependencies {

compile fileTree(dir: '../lib', exclude: ['/**/javaee-api-*.jar'], include: ['/**/*.jar'])
    
compileOnly fileTree(dir: '../lib', include: ['/**/javaee-api-*.jar'])
}
```